# Existe alguma API do google para capturar a informação destaque da busca?

Tags: php, google, google-api

Existe algum API ou algo parecido no qual eu possa capturar a informação destaque de uma busca no google? Por exemplo, quando eu pesquiso "Bill Gates" aparece no quadro da direita algumas informações sobre ele:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse quadro é chamado [Knowledge Graph](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph) e você pode [encontrar a documentação aqui](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/?authuser=1).

Por exemplo, ao fazer essa requisição (você precisará inserir sua chave API):

https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=bill+gates&key=API_KEY&limit=1&indent=True&languages=pt

Você receberá:

```
...
"itemListElement": [{
    "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
    "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/m/017nt",
        "name": "Bill Gates",
        "@type": [
            "Person",
            "Thing"
        ],
        "description": "Magnata",
        "image": {
            "contentUrl": "http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRXjfjE0L0XHKNqiGayo9stzrfNMkJs2wDxs36K1DStW1WqLi4p",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gates",
            "license": "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0"
        },
        "detailedDescription": {
            "articleBody": "William Henry Gates III mais conhecido como Bill Gates, é um magnata, filantropo e autor norte-americano, que ficou conhecido por fundar junto com Paul Allen a Microsoft, a maior e mais conhecida empresa de software do mundo em termos de valor de mercado.\n",
            "url": "http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gates",
            "license": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License"
        },
        "url": "http://www.gatesnotes.com/"
    },
    "resultScore": 675.914368
}]
...
```

O Google usa algumas informações da Wikipedia – como o link logo abaixo da descrição sobre Bill Gates sugere. A Wikipedia utiliza o software MediaWiki, que possui uma [API para consultas](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page). Pode ser interessante também consultar os dados lá.

Por exemplo, fazendo a seguinte requisição:

https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Bill_Gates&section=0&prop=wikitext

Você vai obter:

```
{{Mais notas|data=outubro de 2014}}
{{Info/Biografia
|nome                =Bill Gates
|nome_completo       =William Henry Gates III
|conhecido_por       =ser fundador da [[Microsoft]]
|imagem              =Dts news bill gates wikipedia.JPG
|nascimento_local    =[[Seattle]], [[Condado de King (Washington)|King]], [[Washington]],<br /> {{USA}}
|residência          =[[Medina (Washington)|Medina]], King, Washington, <br />{{USAb}} Estados Unidos
|nacionalidade       =[[Estadunidenses|Norte-americano]]
|fortuna             ={{Increase}} [[Dólar dos Estados Unidos|US$]] 78.3 [[Bilhão|bilhões]] <small>(Agosto 2016)<ref name="net worth">{{cite web|title=#1 Bill Gates|url=http://www.forbes.com/profile/bill-gates/?list=billionaires|publisher=Forbes|accessdate=January 2, 2016}}</ref>
|legenda             =Bill Gates em [[Berlim]] (janeiro de 2013)
|data_nascimento     ={{nowrap|{{dni|lang=br|28|10|1955}}}}

etc...
```

A partir daí, você tem algumas opções para extrair os dados, desde usar regex nessa infobox em wikitext ou modificar a requisição API para retornar o HTML já compilado (`prop=text`), assim você pode usar algum HTML parser em php.

Além da Wikipedia, o Google usa também outras fontes. No caso do Bill Gates, incluíram a fortuna dele a partir dos dados da Forbes. Essa revista também possui uma API, e por aí vai.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado mesmo, vou testar!

Comment: Só uma pergunta rápida, para criar este API precisa pagar? passei rápido pelas etapas e vi aparecia "30 dias" e algo relacionado a monitoramento financeiro.

Comment: E também pensei que meu idioma seria pego automático por causa da API, mas ainda assim ficou em inglês.

Comment: Tem que colocar o idioma na URL conforme a [Referência da Knowledge Graph](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1/), editei a resposta pra corrigir a falta do parâmetro. Tem um limite de consultas gratuito pelo que sei, dá uma olhada lá certinho.

Comment: Então é pago :/, mas muito obrigado, cara!

Comment: Amigo, vai em Cotas no seu Google Cloud Platform (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/kgsearch.googleapis.com/quotas). Lá ele mostra o limite gratuito de 100 mil requisições diárias. Só é necessário pagar pra aumentar esse limite.

Comment: ah sim, entendi, valeu, vou dar uma lida melhor na documentação e etc.